# Pivot Table - Calculating averages and using two filters not at the same time

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to create two different Pivot Tables.

1. The first table will have columns including investor name, initial date of investment, # years as investor, initial investment value, change in investment value. **I would then like to Filter the data either by what I call the "Fund" OR "Channel". So I would like to be able to calculate the average change in investment value and average initial investment value and average number of years as investor while using either of my filters**. IE I will have the average number of years as investor only within a certain "Fund" or "Channel". I am not sure how I can create these averages.
2. The second table is similar, but I need help with both the table and formatting the raw data. What I would like is to be able to take any instance of an Investor and use their first investment value by date as the initial value column, then use the total of all the instances' present values as the Present Value column, in order to calculate the change in initial value to present value for ALL instances. I would then like to make a Pivot table using this information in the same way as my first question.

This is hard to explain so please ask if I am not being clear.

Answer (score -1):

Great question.  I'm curious to read some answers from the experts.